# The volume "boot" has only 0 byte disk space remaining

Tags: linux, ubuntu, filesystems

I am in Ubuntu 10.04.

When I install the software updates with "Update Manager", there is a pop up dialog which tells me

> ```
> The volume "boot" has only 0 byte disk space remaining
> ```

How to get rid of this?

Comment: Your `/boot` partition is full, so you will either have to make it bigger or remove some kernel image files that you don't use anymore. See [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1402004) Ubuntu thread for how to. Often you should post Ubuntu related stuff on http://askubuntu.com/ to get some good answers.

Comment: @hesse As long as it's something that could affect other distros it's fine here too, and I'm pretty sure a full boot partition isn't an Ubuntu-specific problem :)

Comment: Update your question with the output of `ls -Fal /boot`.

Comment: You probably have a separate `/boot` partition and it got filled up. Ubuntu has a bad habit of keeping old kernels around forever, filling the boot partition.  See Gilles's answer for how to relieve that.

Answer (score 6):

Check if you have old kernels that you aren't using. Run `uname -r` to see what kernel version you're running. Then, in the package manager, remove all the `linux-image-VERSION-FLAVOR` packages that are for a different version. For example, if `uname -r` shows `2.6.32-37-generic` (the current version as I write), then remove `linux-image-2.6.32-36-generic`, `linux-image-2.6.32-35-generic`, and so on, as well as other flavors (e.g. `…-generic` if you're using `2.6.32-37-generic-pae`. Also remove the corresponding `linux-headers-…` if you have them.